# How can I unshelve a submitted changelist in perforce?

Tags: perforce

My tree is pretty old. I don't want to `p4 sync` the whole thing just yet, but I do want to "cherry-pick" one change that has since been submitted. How can I do this with either `p4` or `p4v`?

It sounds simple so I'm likely just not searching for the right term. E.g. "unshelving" is only a thing you can do to "shelved" changelists. Whatever. I just want to create a new local CL that's a copy of something already submitted (same branch, no integration, not using streams, just applying a patch that I haven't synced to yet).

---

[edit] for reference, unshelving gets the state of those files and does not apply a diff (like git cherry-pick) so the equivalent command for submitted CLs should probably do the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can sync a specific changelist using the same revision syntax that you would for a cherry-pick integration:

```
p4 sync @CHANGE,@CHANGE
```

Note that syncing a changelist this way isn't quite the same as a cherry-pick or an unshelve because you will be getting each *whole revision* in that change, rather than only the *diffs* in that change applied to some baseline.  It sounds like that's the thing you want, but be aware that if you want to cherry-pick individual diffs, that's an entirely different type of operation (and one that I'd recommend doing in a branch rather than purely locally).

Comment: Thanks! I think this is pretty close. I was hoping to be able to have that revision appear in a pending CL so that I could revert to the have revision if needed. I'm probably thinking too much with a git mindset. For reference, syncing a CL's files is also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940538/how-to-sync-the-perforce-client-only-with-the-files-of-a-particular-change-list).

Comment: You could technically do that with something gnarly like `p4 sync -p @CHANGE,CHANGE` followed by `p4 -F %depotFile% files @CHANGE,CHANGE | p4 -x - edit`.  I think.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is just `sync` (in the CLI) and `Get Latest...` (in P4V)

#### P4 CLI

On the CLI, assuming there is one file you want to get the latest version of, you could do this:

```
p4 sync local/path/in/my/workspace/toTheFile.txt
```

That will just get the latest version of that single file. There are a ton more options with sync, where you can get specific revisions for a file, or revisions up to a certain timestamp in a folder, etc. Check those out in the [sync docs](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_sync.html).

#### P4V

In P4V, you can either right click on the file itself (in the workspace view or the depot view) and then choose Get Latest. That will just sync the file you have selected.

In P4V, you can also choose to sync a specific revision, timestamp, etc. by choosing Get Revision instead of Get Latest.

Comment: Thanks, Jase. I'm actually looking for a way to get only the changes from one specific changelist number. If I sync to the latest, that file would include other changes I don't want and that would conflict with missing changes in other files.

Comment: If you open up the Get Revision... dialog in p4v and select a specific changelist, there should be a checkbox to only get revisions from that changelist.

Comment: IIUC a revision is the state of the file in the history, so syncing specific files to a submitted CL is probably most similar to unshelving since unshelving also just grabs the state rather than applying a diff locally. It'd be nice if I could have that state appear in a local CL (e.g. default) so that I could easily revert back to the "have revision" if I wanted. I noticed there's a "Get Revision" in the p4v history's right click menu too, but nothing similar when viewing the CL itself (e.g. via Ctrl-G).